# Binding not updating WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying bind an int to a label in a simple application. The idea is, when a button is pressed, the int, and hence the label, is updated.

I have simplified the code as much as I can but I am not able to see the problem.

I think the issue is with `NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)` as at runtime start the label's content is updated with the value of the int. However, when the int updates, the label does not.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Press.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Presses: "/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=PressCount}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Press Me" Click="PressMe_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Press
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public int pressCount = 0;

        public int PressCount {
            get {
                return pressCount;
            }
            private set {
                if(value != pressCount)
                {
                    pressCount = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void PressMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PressCount++;
            Console.WriteLine(PressCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dan, I believe you already got a solution, but one suggestion I want to provide that —- let’s segregate ViewModel with View. It would help to write loosely coupled viewmodel logic

Comment: @user1672994 Thank you for the suggestion. This code was already set up in a pattern called MVVM. However when the code wasn't working I stripped everything but bare minimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `MainWindow` to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`